# How might an applied mathematician view $ 1/x$, $\ln x$, and $e^x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, applications

I understand that the natural logarithm was developed by  Gregoire de Saint-Vincent and Alphonse Antonio de Sarasa as to represent the area under the curve of the hyperbola $\frac1x$ before the development of calculus.

The base of the natural logarithm is an irrational number e first observed by John Napier but defined by Jacob Bernoulli when studying compound interest as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Speaking for many, as a non-mathematician I can see the importance of e for modeling continuous growth why it was studied and therefore view the natural logarithm as a way to represent how many cycles of continuous growth a process has gone through.

I would like a deeper understanding of these functions, how does an applied mathematician view these functions?

Does 1/x model any real world processes?

If we did not have a need in the past to simplify calculations with logarithm tables, would logarithms be of central importance in a primary math education?

What is the importance of the natural logarithm and what insight does it give besides being the x in $ x = ln y $ from $ y = e^x $ ?

Comment: One of my favorite topics about exponentiation in a simple context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Applications_and_examples

Comment: Note that you can use MathJaX in titles and that certain common fuctions have their own commands, like $\ln$=`\ln`, $\sin$=`\sin`, etc...

Comment: I am very interested in your question, Anthony. I'll try to write an answer in the following days, as I don't have much time right now. I feel applied mathematics is underrepresented here on m.s.e.